# ERROR in TRIGGER AFTER INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have a problem with the next TRIGGER in SQL server 2008:

```
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Order int,
            @Payment varchar(15)

select @order=OrderID,@payment=PaymentType from inserted

    IF @Payment='paypal'
    begin
            exec PaypalTransactionsUpdate @OrderID=@Order
    end
    ELSE
    begin 
        Return
    end
END
```

I can't understand why does not work the select  from the inserted table. If I use like:

```
select TOP 1 @order=OrderID,@payment=PaymentType from TABLENAME where PaymentType='Paypal' order by OrderID desc.
```

It works perfectly, anybody can help me? I want to use the row table inserted to prevent data errors becuase the second statement is no secure, maybe the top one already changes when the trigger runs.

I was using the top1 select this weekend and was working for some orders and for some one don't for no reason. I saw this morning that the row that I want to synchronize , the trigger do it in the next insert, this means, when Paypal order comes stay there without synchronize until the next order comes and rerun the trigger. I am using the after insert modify method and can't understand why this happens. Any ideas?
I will appreciate as well if someone give me a clue how to test Trigger or see the error log of them.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell us what error you are getting.

Comment: well first thing that jumps out to me is it looks like you're assuming "inserted" only includes one row.  If you happen to perform an insert with multiple rows, this will bomb out due to attempting to write several rows of integers to a single integer variable. (using integers as an example)

Comment: a trigger executes once for the whole `INSERT` transaction, not once for every row inserted. So, the `inserted` seudo table holds all of the rows that were inserted on the table. Your trigger assumes only one row on that table

Comment: Well is a table for Orders, and normally we have 1 order in diferent minutes and is not always paypal, can be Visa. I tried as well to set the variable like : select @Payment=(select PaymentType from inserted):
So my question is , how can i fixed or how can i take that parameter for the row inserted?
I don't know how to see the error, because the table inserted only appear for an insert and i can't make insert only in this table.

Comment: What is the error you are getting @Oscar?

Comment: I don't know how to test a statement when I try to read from an inserted table. That's why I came here to ask if someone can help me with this. Because I really don't know how to teSt a trigger, because I can't add orders to this table. I have to wait for someone who buys something by PayPal to see if my code works or not. How can I test a trigger from an inserted to see the errors @Kyle Copeland

Comment: What if you do `set @order=inserted.OrderID` instead?

Comment: @Lamak, I believe that would be true iff it's bulk insert.